# Регулярное выражение для поиска всех включений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть массив строк, например `['JavaScript', 'Score', 'Scratch', Duscr]`. Мне нужно разработать регулярное выражение, которое бы находило строки с `scr` независимо от:

- регистра,
- позиции в тексте (сначала, в средине, в конце)

То есть должны найтись строки: *Java**Scr**ipt*, ***Scr***atch, *Du**scr***.
Не очень понимаю регулярные выражения, поэтому не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: вхождения чего?

Comment: Во первых не понятна суть задачи. Во вторых ты просишь не подсказки, а решение целиком.

Comment: Что значит - независимо от языка? Вам нужна регулярка, которая работает как переводчик? O_o

Comment: «кидаю» ссылку: [джеффри фридл, регулярные выражения](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4066500/). удалось поймать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при переборе массива можно проверять так

```js
var test = /scr/i.test('JavaScript');
console.log(test);

test = /scr/i.test('Score');
console.log(test);
```

флаг:

i - указывает, что ищем независимо от регистра

Comment: Никогда не используйте модификатор `g` с `RegExp#test`, это может привести к непредсказуемым результатам (вместо `true` можно получить `false` и наоборот).

Comment: А вот и проблема - [Особенности регулярок в js?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721417).