# Особенности регулярок в js?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
addIpToArray() {
    let newIp = '';
    isEmpty(this.mask) ? newIp = this.ip : newIp = this.ip + '/' + this.mask;
    console.log(newIp)
    let test = this.regexp.test(newIp)
    console.log(test)
}
```

Нужно провалидировать айпишник с маской.
Возвращает true, false, true, false. т.е. при каждой итерации разное значание. В чем может быть проблема? 
Регулярка:

```
/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$/g
```

Comment: Дайте достаточно полный код, чтобы мы его запустили у себя и получили эти самые true false true false

Comment: Мне кажется, что на форуме вопрос про валидацию IP регуляркой уже был.

Comment: @andreymal, тут и без него ясно.

Comment: @nick_n_a, мне кажется этот вопрос про регулярку для проверки ip.

Comment: Вот есть проверка регуляркой IP https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706722/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-ip-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9

Comment: @nick_n_a, но вопрос-то совсем не об этом. Тут у автора уже есть интересующая его регулярка, которая работает через раз. Загляни в мой ответ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В чем может быть проблема?

Убери у регулярки флаг `g`. Из-за него она пытается продолжать поиск с прошлого вхождения вместо того, чтобы проверять строку.

```js
var r1 = /^.$/, r2 = /^.$/g;

console.log(["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(s => r1.test(s)).join(" "));
console.log(["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(s => r2.test(s)).join(" "));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: @НикитаЛeдовской См. на англ. [Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results). Эта "проблема" слишком популярна, почти каждую неделю кто-нибудь такой вопрос задаёт.